# Regular expression that matches the third instance of something? (python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match the third instance of a / in a url, i.e. so that only the website's name itself will be recorded, nothing else.

So http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/answers/help/ after being put through the regex will be http://www.stackoverflow.com

I've been playing about with them myself and come up with:

```
base_url = re.sub(r'[/].*', r'', url)
```

but all this does is reduce a link to http: - so it's obvious I need to match the third instance of / - can anyone explain how I would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) for parsing URLs:

```
In [1]: from urlparse import urlparse

In [2]: urlparse('http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/answers/help/').netloc
Out[2]: 'www.stackoverflow.com'
```

`.netloc` includes the port number if present (e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com:80`); if you don't want the port number, use `.hostname` instead.

Comment: ahh I never knew this existed, makes life a whole lot easier! thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 3):

URLParse would work, but since you originally asked about Regexes, try a positive match instead of a negative substitution:

```
match = re.match(r'.+://[^/]+', url);
baseUrl = match.group();
```

This will grab the `http://` (or `https://`, or `ftp://`), and everything after it until the first `/`.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm

Comment: this worked perfectly - but I think I will go with urlparse - thanks a lot though =)